# Do function calls on contracts return any data to the sender?

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm playing around with Solidity in Remix and I noticed the console will output transactions such as:

```
 from    - 
 to     browser/Untitled3.sol:HelloWorld.greeting() 0x5e72914535f202659083db3a02c984188fa26e9f
 transaction cost   23147 gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract)
 execution cost     1875 gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract)
 input  ef690cc0
 decoded input  {}
 decoded output     {
    "0": "string: Hey world, this is a smart contract!"
}
 logs   []
```

When a user calls a function on a contract, do they get this sort of data spit back at them? Specifically, the `output` field in the above log. Or is this just a part of the IDE for development purposes? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you call a function marked as constant/view you'll get the return value/s of the function.

If you make a transaction you'll just get the transaction hash immediatelly and later you can retrieve the transaction info.